# React adding conditional styling (&&)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

the same newbie here.
I have the code which working as intended, all I want to do is add `&&` with `state` variable  (boolean) to make a text have line-through decoration while clicked (using crossedItemOnClick)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Para(props) {
    const {id, className, info, state} = props;
    

    return (
        <p onClick={props.crossedItemOnClick} id={id} className={className} style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>{info}</p>
    )
}

export default Para;
```

My whole page disappears if I change it to:

```
        <p onClick={props.crossedItemOnClick} id={id} className={className} style={state && {textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>{info}</p>
```

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong and why the page completely disappears. And of course explanation to learn if you'd be kind to.
Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct, however, your condition should be applied on the style property directly like this if you want to use &&

```
style={{textDecorationLine: state && 'line-through'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `style` prop expect object of type `CSSProperties`, and in case when your condition is false you will end up with something like `style={false}` which will cause your app to crash since you provided HTML element with invalid styling.

Easiest solution is to just rewrite that part to `style={state ? {...someStyle} : {}}`

Answer (score 2):

style attribute takes `object` as value in react. Correct way will be:

```js
<p onClick={props.crossedItemOnClick} id={id} className={className} style={state ? {textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}:{}}>{info}</p>
```

assuming you have to apply the style when state is true.